# How can I compute the difference in Y-axis values between data sets with similar X-values

Tags: plotting, matrix

I am new to *Mathematica*, so this might be a very basic question; however, I cannot find a solution to this and it is taking me very long.

For my research I am probing the photoluminescence response of a organic film with and without an external magnetic field, and also take a background measurement with and without the field. This generates large data files, with equal x values (wavelengths) and different y values (intensity) with dimensions `{3648, 2}`. I would like to `ListPlot` the difference between the data, but when I do something like this:

```
Signal = WithMagnet - WithoutMagnet
```

I end up with a vertical line at x=0.

Can anyone here help me how to plot the difference in y-values while keeping the x-axis the same as in the individual files?

Hope someone can help me with this! Cheers

Comment: Post a link to the data (or a portion of the data here in readable/copy-paste format) and the code you have been using to plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) to subtract intensity and [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) to align with the wavelength data:

```
wavelength = Range[350, 750, (400/3647)];

withMagnet = Transpose[{wavelength, RandomReal[1, 3648]}];
withoutMagnet = Transpose[{wavelength, RandomReal[1, 3648]}];

(*The above code just simulates your imported data*)

diff = Transpose[{withoutMagnet[[All, 1]], 
                  withMagnet[[All, 2]] - withoutMagnet[[All, 2]]}];

ListLinePlot[diff, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You transpose twice, I do not have to do that right? I now do the following:

    'Analyse = 
    Transpose[{without1[[All, 1]], 
    with1[[All, 2]] - without1[[All, 2]]}];
    ListPlot[Aanalyse, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> Emission, 
    AxesLabel -> {wavelength, arbitrary units}, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Orange]]' 

That should give me the correct graph right? As the photoluminescence should be stronger for this film and it has not been showing me good results, I do not really know what to expect from the data, but it looks correct.

Comment: Great, thanks! Sorry didn't know how to do that, but did it just now!